# Why is this insert corrupting my table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, corruption, insert-into

After I run this, I cannot select or drop the table.

I also never got the rollback or error

**mytable**:

```
cmid pk in not null
cmcid int null
cmctitle nvarchar(4000)
```

Query:

```
begin transaction
INSERT INTO [mydatabasename].[dbo].[mytable]
           (cmcid,cmctitle)
         values(396,'*ADVANCED 2-D ART – Painting  &amp; Drawing'),
(397,'Advanced 3D Art'),
(398,'AP Studio Art')
(399,'Digital Art'),
(400,'Intro to Visual Art'),
(401,'Bible 9 - Scripture'),
(402,'Bible 10 - God  &amp; Christ'),
(403,'Bible 11 -Doctrine and World Religions'),
(404,'Bible 12 - Worldviews'),
(405,'Accounting'),
(406,'AP Macroeconomics'),
(407,'AP Microeconomics'),
(408,'Personal Finance'),
(409,'Introduction to Life Calling'),
(410,'*ACADEMIC SKILLS'),
(411,'*BASIC SKILLS TRAINING – Resource'),
(412,'Directed Studies'),
(413,'*INTERNATIONAL STUDENT SEMINAR'),
(414,'*STUDENT ACHIEVEMENT TRAINING'),
(415,'AP Language and Composition 11'),
(416,'American Literature 11'),
(417,'British Literature 12'),
(418,'Grammar  &amp; Composition 9'),
(419,'*ENGLISH 10 – World Literature'),
(420,'Honors American Literature 11'),
(421,'Honors British Literature 12'),
(422,'Honors Dramatic Literature'),
(423,'Honors World Lit and Composition 10'),
(424,'World Literature  &amp; Composition 10'),
(425,'*HONORS SHAKESPEAREAN COMEDIES'),
(426,'Speech'),
(427,'Yearbook'),
(428,'AP Calculus'),
(429,'AP Statistics'),
(430,'Algebra 1'),
(431,'Algebra 1 with Lab'),
(432,'Algebra 2'),
(433,'Geometry'),
(434,'Honors Geometry'),
(435,'PreCalculus'),
(436,'Introduction to Life Calling'),
(437,'Missions'),
(438,'*ADVANCED MUSIC THEORY'),
(439,'*ADVANCED ORCHESTRA'),
(440,'Concert Band'),
(441,'HS Chapel Praise  &amp; Worship Team'),
(442,'Encore'),
(443,'Colla Voce'),
(444,'Musical Theatre'),
(445,'Jazz Band'),
(446,'Intro to Music Theory'),
(447,'HS Orchestra  &amp; Ensemble'),
(448,'Theater Production'),
(449,'*THEATRE ARTS'),
(450,'Theater Production'),
(451,'*ADVANCED PE, STRENGTH  &amp; CONDITIONING '),
(452,'Physical Education - Health'),
(453,'*HEALTH – Girls'),
(454,'Physical Education for Boys'),
(455,'Physical Education for Girls'),
(456,'Physical Education for Athletes'),
(457,'Physical Education Advanced Weight Training'),
(458,'AP Biology'),
(459,'*ADVANCED PLACEMENT CHEMISTRY'),
(460,'Bioethics'),
(461,'Biology 1'),
(462,'Botany'),
(463,'*BIOLOGY II - ZOOLOGY'),
(464,'Biomedical Sciences Professional Seminar'),
(465,'Chemistry'),
(466,'Honors Biology 1'),
(467,'Honors Bio II = Physiology'),
(468,'Honors Chemistry'),
(469,'Honors Physics'),
(470,'Integrated Chemistry-Physics'),
(471,'Zoology'),
(472,'*SCIENCE RESEARCH - INDEPENDENT STUDY'),
(473,'AP Government'),
(474,'AP US History'),
(475,'Civil War  &amp; Reconstruction'),
(476,'Economics'),
(477,'Geography and History of the World'),
(478,'Psychology'),
(479,'Sociology'),
(480,'Government'),
(481,'US History'),
(482,'*TEACHER ASSISTANCE'),
(483,'Video Production'),
(484,'*ADVANCED PLACEMENT COMPUTER SCIENCE'),
(485,'*DATABASE APPLICATION'),
(486,'Computer Programming'),
(487,'*VIDEO PRODUCTION'),
(488,'Web Design'),
(489,'French 1'),
(490,'French 2'),
(491,'French 3'),
(492,'Honors French 4'),
(493,'Latin I'),
(494,'Latin II'),
(495,'Latin III'),
(496,'Spanish 1'),
(497,'Spanish 2'),
(498,'Spanish 3'),
(499,'Honors Spanish 4'),
(500,'Honors Spanish 5')

go
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
   PRINT 'error!'
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all: at the end of your `INSERT`s, if everything is OK, you need to **`COMMIT`** the transaction!

Otherwise no data is actually inserted into the table, and you're placing a lock on the table (so you cannot select from it anymore - while that transaction is still open and waiting to the committed or rolled back).

So your `INSERT` is **not corrupting** your table - you're just leaving your transaction in an open state, and the table is (partially) locked while that is the case.

And also: if it's a `NVARCHAR` column, you should **always** use an `N'` prefix in your inserts! Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [mydatabasename].[dbo].[mytable](cmcid, cmctitle)
VALUES(396, N'*ADVANCED 2-D ART – Painting  &amp; Drawing')` . 
            *
            *-- this N prefix is important!
```

Otherwise, your string being inserted is converted back to **non-Unicode** before being inserted into the Unicode-capable `NVARCHAR` column!

You didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - if you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer, you should really use the [`TRY ... CATCH` mechanism of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to do your error handling - something like:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction

  INSERT .....

  COMMIT TRANSACTION  -- if successful - *COMMIT* your transaction
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   -- if error, roll back your transaction
END CATCH
```

Comment: this is all really help and worked no problems. thanks so much.  i need this table up monday morning.  And what you say makes sense.  i have never had errors with sql so i just dont bother.  but after this nonsense.  it is not much to add this around it.  to be honest it has also confused me.  go, begin, end, begin try, begin transaction..... and case in point, if you don't understand it, some times they mess things up and so there is some logic if it works without it. same with the N' didn't know and it did not seem to matter.  i ran it an it worked great and now i can enjoy my day off.

Comment: BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction
INSERT INTO [SQL2008R2_770505_clubs].[dbo].[Web_Classes_clink]
           (ccid,cctitle)
         values

(396,N'*ADVANCED 2-D ART – Painting  &amp; Drawing'),
(397,N'Advanced 3D Art')COMMIT TRANSACTION  -- if successful - *COMMIT* your transaction
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   -- if error, roll back your transaction
END CATCH

Comment: @misterg: if this answer helped you solve your problem, you should [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: this is what i mean now ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANS
MERGE dbo.Web_Classes AS Target
USING (SELECT ccid,cctitle FROM Web_Classes_clink) AS Source
 --test on one record  example 
  --ON (Target.tid1 = Source.tid and Target.tid1 = '707586')
  ON (Target.silvertitle = Source.cctitle and source.ccid = 408)
--ON (Target.silvertitle = Source.cctitle)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.silvertitle = Source.cctitle
     OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
     
     END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   -- if error, roll back your transaction
END CATCH

Comment: @misterg: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.